# Symfony 4 - Custom Folder structure and Services

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm looking to implement a folder structure recommended by [Nikola Posa](https://blog.nikolaposa.in.rs/2017/01/16/on-structuring-php-projects/).

The structure I would like is something like what is below.

```
src/
   Domain/
      User/
         UserEntity.php
         UserController.php
      Pages/
         DefaultPageController.php
```

The idea is to logically group/namespace features or similar content.  I seem to be getting this error:

> The file "../src/Controller" does not exist (in: /Users/dev/Sites/web/html/sandbox/php/crud/config) in /Users/dev/Sites/web/html/sandbox/php/crud/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/Users/dev/Sites/web/html/sandbox/php/crud/config/services.yaml").

I'm not sure how important it is to wire up these as services.  If I comment out the `App\Controller` property of the `services.yaml`, it goes away.

How can I load controllers in service.yaml with a `src/Domain/Feature/FeatureController.php` structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course go old school and just define each controller service individually:

```
# config/services.yaml
Domain\Feature\FeatureController:
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

However, once you get used to autowire then spelling out each service is a pain.  As an alternative you can use the autoconfigure capability to add the controller tag to selected classes.  Start by declaring an empty interface and have your controllers implement it:

```
interface ControllerInterface {}

class SomeController implements ControllerInterface
```

Then adjust src/Kernel.php

```
# src/Kernel.php
class Kernel {
    protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->registerForAutoconfiguration(ControllerInterface::class)
            ->addTag('controller.service_arguments');
```

Of course this just takes care of the controller issue.  You will probably encounter a number of other autowire related issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would go and create a Controller interface like Cerad suggest. However, since [Symfony 3.3](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-simpler-service-configuration#combining-default-and-interface-based-configuration) you don't have to touch the kernel:

```
services:
    _instanceof:
        YourApp\Ui\ControllerInterface:
            public: true
            tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Et voila.